# cluster 2d matrix (clustring)

Tags: python, clustering, k-means, 2d

i have a 2d Matrix and It contains specifications for laptops, where each group contains three components like thant :

```
[['8 gigabytes', 'Intel 9th Generation Core i7', '512 gigabytes']
, ['16 gigabytes', 'Intel 9th Generation Core i7', '1000 gigabytes']
, ['16 gigabytes', 'Intel 10th Generation Core i7', '512 gigabytes']
, ['16 gigabytes', 'Intel 9th Generation Core i7', '1256 gigabytes']
, ['16 gigabytes', 'Intel 10th Generation Core i7', '512 gigabytes']
, ['16 gigabytes', 'Intel 9th Generation Core i7', '512 gigabytes']
, ['16 gigabytes', 'Intel 9th Generation Core i7', '512 gigabytes']
, ['16 gigabytes', 'Intel 9th Generation Core i7', '512 gigabytes']]
```

Where I want to collect and classify this data according to three factors (gaming, casual, business) using kmeans or anyting else .
[image]
can someone help me with that .thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is your data about those factors?

Comment: I have dataframe , looks like this,

Comment: I have dataframe , looks like this,
`      systemMemoryRam                 processorModel totalStorageCapacity
0      16 gigabytes  Intel 10th Generation Core i7        512 gigabytes

..              ...                            ...                  ...`

Comment: I don't see any information that tells us the "gaming, casual, business" classifications.  You can't cluster observations based on data you don't have.

Comment: Actually I want to classify my data in a new field containing (gaming,casual,buisniss)
Based on the data

Comment: I'm at a complete loss to understand what you hope to accomplish: you state you *don't* have this information but you want to use it for classification.

Comment: How do we clustring   the data  k = 3  without saying anything?

Comment: This would be called "unsupervised clustering."  There are a huge number of ways to do it.  You need to think about how to quantify what it means for two laptops to be "similar" and how to use that to distinguish one cluster from another.